# Tab control with data templates in wpf MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I want to load the number of tabs according to the list of case and each tap want to show the detail of a case. A case will have text and collection of list also.
Following is my code can't be able to load the content

```
                    <CheckBox Content="Tab  " d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" FontFamily="{StaticResource BoldFontFamily}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14.667"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Name="ContentTemplate1">
                    <Grid Margin="10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="230"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ID}"></TextBlock>
                        <ListBox x:Name="lbItems" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="100" Style="{StaticResource PT_ListBoxStyle}" 
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}" >
                        <ListBox.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate">
                                <Grid d:DesignWidth="623.375" Margin="0,5">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}" FontSize="21.333" Text="{Binding IText}" Width="721" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}" FontSize="21.333" Width="Auto" Text="{Binding IType}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}" FontSize="21.333" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding IAmount}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.Resources>
                    </ListBox>
                 </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

Above is my code of XML and... In my view model,

```
 private List<Case> _cases = new List<Case>(); 
   public List<Case> Cases { get { return _cases; } set { _cases = value; } }
public void GetList() 
 { 
 List<Case> cases = Customer.GetTabDetails(date); 
  Cases=cases; 
 }
```

Above the view model code. Case class has ID, List of Items, List of Customers etc properties

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Please keep all the code of the question in the question. Do not spam the answers with details of the question just add to the question. This site does not use the forum/discussion format.

Answer (score 0):

Define the template explicitly as the `ListBox`s `ItemTemplate` rather than a dynamic resource. I would avoid dynamic resource wherever possible!

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ContentTemplate1">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbItems" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}" 
                 Style="{StaticResource PT_ListBoxStyle}" 
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"      
                 MinHeight="100">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Grid d:DesignWidth="623.375" Margin="0,5">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}" FontSize="21.333" Text="{Binding IText}" Width="721" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}" FontSize="21.333" Width="Auto" Text="{Binding IType}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontFamily="{StaticResource RegularFontFamily}" FontSize="21.333" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding IAmount}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But  still i have a problem. If my database return 2 cases, it can create 2 tabs but no data bind with tab. i have checked my viewmodel. it has the data for the item source bind with listbox. What can i do now?

Comment: Can you post your ViewModels?

Comment: View Model have big line of codes..Sorry. In my method i return the data as a ObservableCollection list and bind with tab control

Comment: It is really hard to help without more information. Try to post the relevant parts of the ViewModel.

Comment: i have attach my code below..pls refer and suggest a solution